# How to convert SQL Server procedure to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How could I convert the following code to be used with MySQL? I'm a little familiar with MySQL but not familiar with SQL Server .

```
create procedure spInsertAccount
(
@AccountID INT,
@InUse bit,
@IsBanned bit,
@IsPremium bit,
@IsGolden bit,
@Username VARCHAR(20),
@Password VARCHAR(20),
@Email VARCHAR(65),
@LoggedInID INT,
@CreateDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = @AccountID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Accounts
    values(@AccountID,@InUse,@IsBanned,@IsPremium,@IsGolden,@Username,@Password,@Email,@LoggedInID,@CreateDate)

    select @@IDENTITY as [NewAccountID]
END

IF @@ERROR = 1 
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
ELSE 
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from basic syntactic conventions, you are testing if a record exists and then doing an insert if it doesn't.  This is being wrapped in a transaction, to be sure that the condition and the `insert` "see" the same picture of the database.

In both databases, you can eliminate the transaction by doing:

```
INSERT INTO Accounts(AccountID, InUse, IsBanned, IsPremium, IsGolden, Username, Password,
                    Email, LoggedInID, CreateDate
                   )
    select @AccountID, @InUse, @IsBanned, @IsPremium, @IsGolden, @Username, @Password,
          @Email, @LoggedInID, @CreateDate
    where NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = @AccountID);
```

Next, I have two problems with this statement:    `select @@IDENTITY as [NewAccountID]`.

First, this suggests that you have an identity column (which would be `auto_increment` in MySQL).  But, you don't list the columns in the `insert` statement.  That means that you probably have an error in MS SQL, because you (generally) can't insert a value into an identity column.  As is always good practice anyway, I list all the columns in the insert.

Second, you never use the value.  So, just eliminate the statement.

With these changes, the MS SQL procedure body becomes:

```
as begin 
   INSERT INTO Accounts(AccountID, InUse, IsBanned, IsPremium, IsGolden, Username, Password,
                        Email, LoggedInID, CreateDate
                       )
        select @AccountID, @InUse, @IsBanned, @IsPremium, @IsGolden, @Username, @Password,
               @Email, @LoggedInID, @CreateDate
        where NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = @AccountID);
 end;
```

THis eliminates what I think of as the tricky parts of the conversion.  Actually writing this in MySQL syntax should be pretty easy from here.